# appending return status to associative array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

How to append return status of a command and loop through the associative array and print the results. It seems to be simple and working with sample code but not working in a function. 
I tried quoting the keys and values to push to array but values are not printed. I did checked the return status after appending to array and it is success. However, it is not having the values in the associative array.

The array is not getting the values assigned correctly and hence values are not printed as expected.

The same code is working in my bash version.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A combo
combo+=(['foo']='bar')
combo+=(['hello']='world')
for window in "${!combo[@]}"
do
    echo "The key: ${window}" # foo
    echo "The value: ${combo[${window}]}" # bar
done
```

How to capture the return status of 0 when maven build succeeded and 1 when failure and assign to associative array and print the results from associative array after build ran for all the repositories.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A GITARRAY=(
        [git_token]=user-devops:ggc4ktalwfbf5jiqdsdhmmgj2jvvhj3ltfzdujxzxnmhj45qk525kq
        [git_branch]='development'
)
declare -A GITREPOS=(
        [repository1]=org.gitrepo.com/LIBS/_git/repository1
        [repository2]=org.gitrepo.com/LIBS/_git/repository2
)

declare -A BUILDSTATUS

target_dir=$HOME/womsrc
BASEDIR=`dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")"`
HELLOTO=`whoami`
maven_goal=compile

#repositories modifed to dummy values
REPOS=(reposiroty1 repository2)

main() {

echo "In main fuction: maven goal: $maven_goal"

if [ -n "$maven_goal" ] ; then

for REPO in "${REPOS[@]}"
do
 if [ -d "$target_dir/$REPO/.git" ] ; then
      echo "[INFO] invoking compilation for service in $REPO ..."
      service_dir="$target_dir/$REPO/$REPO"
      build_status=$(buildService $REPO $maven_goal $service_dir)
      echo "[STATUS] mvn:$maven_goal $REPO: $build_status"
 fi
done
fi  ## mavengoal end here


echo "printing build status"
for bt in "${!BUILDSTATUS[@]}"
do
    echo "key: ${bt} result: ${BUILDSTATUS[${bt}]}"  
done

} 

buildService() {
 servicename="$1"
 mavengoal="$2"
 servicedir="$3"
 cd "${servicedir}" || echo "[ERROR] cd to $servicename failed with $?"
 echo "[INFO] starting compilation in `pwd` ..."
 LOG_FILE="$COMPILE_LOGPATH/project-$servicename.log"
 mvn $mavengoal -l $LOG_FILE
 if [ "$?" -eq 0 ] ; then
   buildstatus=success
 else
   buildstatus=failure
 fi
  BUILDSTATUS+=([${servicename}]=${buildstatus})
  echo "Adding BUILDSTATUS return value: $?"
  echo "${BUILDSTATUS[${servicename}]}"
}


main
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and not your whole codebase? ;-)

Comment: @MichaelJaros - updated the minimal code and hope it is clear for reading.

Comment: Your code is pretty readable, but the example is still not minimal. I tried my best to answer your question without missing anything in the time available, see below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your call of the function `buildService()` via command substitution (`$()`) is executed in a child process and cannot affect the `BUILDSTATUS` variable in the parent process, or as the `bash(1)` manual page puts it:

> Command substitution, [...] are invoked in a subshell environment that is a duplicate of the shell environment [...] Changes made to the subshell environment cannot affect the shell's execution environment.

I would suggest outputting only the build status of the current maven call inside `buildService()` and adding that to `BUILDSTATUS` in the calling process. You currently have several other `echo` statements in there. You need to redirect them somewhere else, or they will mess up your assignment to `build_status` in the calling process.

Comment: command substitution does not affect the sub shell commands in the function. do you think multiple echo statements in the function buildService() will go to BUILDSTATUS. I was under impression only the last echo statement from the buildService() will be saved in BUILDSTATUS variable. I created a new file with the minimal code and add the new functions and removed all the echo statements which is working now. I have the same code in the other script but not working for some reason which I could not figure out. Its tricky.thanks Michael for saving my time.

Comment: yes, currently you are assigning all `echo` output from `build_service()` to `build_status` in `main()`. If you do need those diagnostic echos there, you could redirect them to stderr so they don't land in your `build_status`: `echo bla >&2`.

Comment: removed all the echo statements inside the function. Its clear that last echo will be send to calling function.